# Is it possible to keep track of how many times a file is ever opened over time?

Tags: file

To repeat the title basically, is it possible to keep track of how many times a file is ever opened over time?

Comment: Define "opened". Also, maybe, "possible". Is rewriting the filesystem an option?

Comment: Operating systems don't generally keep track of such things. To get any useful answers you'll have to be more specific about what application and/or operating system you need to watch. Also what programming language(s) are you using? Is this actually a programming question?

Comment: @Boann I have access to MS Access, Excel, Python, and I can make C++ executables I suppose, etc. I use Windows 7. I'm mostly interested in checking how often certain Excel files are opened in order to gauge which reports are useful/not useful/etc.

Comment: Sounds like a filesystem API hook would be useful here, like Procmon does, because then your program could watch all filesystem activity. But I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this class FileSystemWatcher:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.aspx

With it, I'm not sure you'll be able to tell when files are opened, but definitely if they are updated.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Windows 7, you could probably try enabling [Global Object Access Auditing](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2011/03/10/global-object-access-auditing-is-magic.aspx). Whatever you are using will need to access the log to view the file access audits. I haven't tried this feature myself, but it's something you could try out.